# How render CCClippingNode correctly to CCRenderTexture

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x

I want to render CCClippingNode into a CCRenderTexture but what I get is just a flat texture.

this is what I want :

[image]

this is what I get :

[image]
>

code fragment from Custom CCRenderTexture subclass:

```
    CCClippingNode* clipper = CCClippingNode::create(maskSprite);
    clipper->setAlphaThreshold(0);
    clipper->addChild(textureSprite);

    begin();

    clipper->visit();

    end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it:

```
    textureSprite->setBlendFunc((ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE, GL_ZERO});
    maskSprite->setBlendFunc((ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO});

    begin();

    textureSprite->visit();
    maskSprite->visit();
    textureSprite->setBlendFunc((ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_ALPHA, GL_ZERO});
    textureSprite->visit();

    end();
```